# How to store a function's return value within the main function. C Programming

Tags: c, function, return

I had to write a program in which part of it had to be able to tell the whether or not a word is a palindrome. My solution to that was this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define maxLen 100

int main() {
    char string[maxLen];
    char stringCopy[maxLen];

    printf("Please enter a string between 2 and 100 characters\n");
    gets(string);
    strcpy(stringCopy,string);
    strrev(stringCopy);

    if(strcmp(string,stringCopy) == 0){
        printf("%s is a palindrome\n\n",string);
    }
    else{
        printf("%s is not a palindrome\n\n",string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now I am having to re write the program only using functions. I am trying to write the code now like this, but keep coming across the problem of not knowing how to use my function's return value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define maxLen 100

int pallindrome(char);

int main(){
    int rValue; // return value
    char pString[maxLen];

    printf("Please enter a string between 2 and 100 characters\n");
    gets(pString);
    int palindrome(char pString);

    rValue = palindrome(char pString);

    if(rValue == 0){
        printf("%s is a palindrome\n",pString);
    }
    else{
        printf("%s is not a palindrome\n",pString);
    }
    return 0;
}

int palindrome(char pString){
    char string;
    string = pString;
    char stringCopy;

    strcpy(stringCopy,string);
    strrev(stringCopy);

    if(strcmp(string,stringCopy) == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use the return value of palindrome() to let the user know whether or not something is a palindrome.

To summarize, I'd like to know if there is a way I can store the return value from a function as a variable within the main function so I can work with it there.

Comment: I assume it's the bottom piece of code that you're talking about. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Your problem is that you are confused about how to call functions and how to refer to c strings. Return value is fine. You want to use `char *` to refer to entire strings, remember that `char` is just 1 char. If you need new strings, you need arrays or allocated memory.

Comment: @Keith You couldn't elaborate? Your comment is a perfect candidate for "not constructive/off topic".

Comment: @meagar thats the joy of comments!  can't do anything but +1 them :)

Comment: `palindrome()` will not do what you are expecting. I recommend going over how to pass a `char[]` to a function.

Comment: @Keith No, you can flag them, which people should be doing instead of "+1"ing them. You're adding to the "noise" side of the coveted signal-to-noise ratio that makes this site worth-while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are nicer ways to solve this problem, but to put your code into a function...

```
int palindrome(char* string)
{
    char stringCopy[maxLen];
    strcpy(stringCopy,string);
    strrev(stringCopy);
    return strcmp(string,stringCopy) == 0;
}
int main() 
 {
    char string[maxLen];
    printf("Please enter a string between 2 and 100 characters\n");
    gets(string);

    if(palindrome(string)){
       printf("%s is a palindrome\n\n",string);
    }
    else{
       printf("%s is not a palindrome\n\n",string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if you want to put it into a variable you could do

```
int main() 
 {
    char string[maxLen];
    int result;
    printf("Please enter a string between 2 and 100 characters\n");
    gets(string);

    result = palindrome(string);
    if(result){
       printf("%s is a palindrome\n\n",string);
    }
    else{
       printf("%s is not a palindrome\n\n",string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I understand it a lot better now. :D

Answer (score 0):

Your palindrome function is wrong. You are just passing a character instead of string. In order to pass string, the function argument should be like `char *pString` or `char pString[]`. Brush up the fundamentals of the language and start coding.